# fullcross mouse pointer option in matlab figures

Tags: matlab, user-interface, pointers

I was looking to have the mouse pointer as fullcross instead of arrow when I move it on top of my image. Looks like MATLAB doesnt support 'fullcross'. To be more specific, I would like the pointer to be a fullcross but a hole at the intersection(sort of able to look at the image at the intersection).

Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks,
Bala

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the undocumented `Pointer` property of figures (look [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-mouse-pointer-functions) for a complete list). You can also customize mouse pointer using the undocumented function `setptr()`.

Anyhow here is what I think you mean by fullcross (fullcrosshair according to Matlab):

```
clear
clc
close all

A = imread('peppers.png');

hFig = figure;
imshow(A)

set(hFig, 'Pointer', 'fullcrosshair');
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply. That is exactly what I want but unfortunately looks like MATLAB doesnt support fullcrosshair anymore. 
"Warning: Full crosshair pointer is no longer supported. A crosshair pointer will be used instead."
Any workaround to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Oh shoot then I don't know. Depending on what you want to do, you could use `ginput` to generate this pointer; its the default when using that function but I don't know if that would work for your application

Comment: Also I don't have access to R2014b so I can't test anything :(

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.
I ended up drawing 2 lines (horizontal and vertical) using the coordinates and it works decently. That would suffice for now I guess. Thanks!